# Show record not found in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <div class="row" *ngIf="activeRoute == 'user'">
            <div *ngIf="userDetails | async as details else noRecord">
            <ul  *ngFor="let info of userDetails | async">
                <li>
                    <span class="text flex-auto pr-2" >{{ info.Name }} </span> 
                </li>
            </ul> 
            </div>
            <ng-template #noRecord>List Empty</ng-template>
  </div>
```

In `ts file`

```
get Details() {
    return this.Service.UserInfoDetails;
}
```

> Service File

```
UserInfoDetails=new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
```

this is working but i want to check if `Details` is blank or does not contain any value then i want to show `No records found` in the `li`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="activeRoute == 'user'">
  <div *ngIf="userDetails | async as details else loading">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!details">No records found</ng-container>
    <ul *ngFor="let info of details">
      <li>
        Text
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div> 

<ng-template #loading> loading ... </ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer there is one more outer div `<div class="row" *ngIf="activeRoute == 'user'">` above `<ul>` i have to place `<ng-template>` within that div?

Comment: You have to place it somewhere in the component. It will just be placed at wherever your `ngIf` referencing the template is located.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner This is not working i tried if data is blank no message is there and message is there only on the initial page load after that data is displayed and when there is no record in db then also message is not shown

Comment: @user3653474 it should indeed work anywhere in the component
can you share your code that isn't working?

Comment: @Robert Can you please check the issue i have updated my code it does not count the length of record i think, when the page loads while loading it shows `List Empty` then after data loads it shows data and `List Empty` is removed but if the data is not present in our database and row is `0` then it should show `List Empty` but this is not happening in my case, Can you please check

Comment: @user3653474 my bad, updated the solution please check now

Comment: and please remove the second `| async` because that way it will call the API twice, just use details in the `ngFor`